# Windows Phone 8.1 app crashing on startup

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having a frustrating issue developing for Windows Phone 8.1 and hoped somebody might have lived through the same thing.

I've had the app running on my phone from a few different deployment packages I created. I recently started deploying directly from VS to my phone when debugging. Everything is working fine. However, when I try to run the app without VS attached, it crashes after the splash screen, with no exception details given. It simply closes.

I've added a handler to the UnhandledException event that will output exception details to a dialog, but this is not displaying anything. The crash only ever occurs when starting the app from the phone.

I reverted to creating a deployment package and deploying that using the tool. However, this version also crashes on start with no message.

Weirder still, I've used one of the deployment packages that had been working fine, and I get the same error: crash, with no message.

I just don't understand this behaviour. Why has an old package that used to work stopped working? I'm using roaming data and considered it might be to do with that, but I really have no other ideas. Please help!

Comment: Are you using any async methods right after the splash screen?

Comment: upload your sample app to onedrive to share with us to check it or give details of the same

Comment: I had the exact same problem, make sure that the same version of BCL dlls (eg. HttpClient)  is used in all projects.

Comment: Fred, there are some async methods being used, ones from SQLite library.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I've checked and they're all the same.

Comment: Roaming data/settings could definitely be causing the issue. If there's a crash while reading them and if they read them at startup. Try completely uninstalling the app then reinstalling. Also, there are certain exceptions (native exceptions generally) that will not trigger the UnhandledException event. It is unreliable in that respect.

Comment: Are you trying to write to the install location? SQLite can do this if you're not careful (it works when debugging with VS, but not in a Store app -- see [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/05/30/sqlite-winrt-wrapper-for-windows-phone/)). Or perhaps you are missing a capability declaration?

Comment: OK, the app has an SQLite database file that is read from shortly after startup. When stored in RoamingFolder, the app crashes. If stored in LocalFolder, no crash. I prefer to use RoamingFolder, but it's not essential.

Comment: are you using pcl libraries? did you have your problem solved?